# When sent to a constructor in Java, what does "null" value do?

Tags: java, constructor, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which constructor is chosen when passing null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021733/which-constructor-is-chosen-when-passing-null)

I recently came across this curiosity while coding a few days back and can't seem to figure out why the following happens:

Given the class below

```
public class RandomObject{
    public RandomObject(Object o){
        System.out.println(1);
    }
    public RandomObject(String[] s){ 
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
```

When the call `new RandomObject(null);` is made the output is always `2` regardless of the order in which the constructors were created. Why does `null` refer to the string array rather than the object?

Comment: @guido the other question involves 2 non-`Object`s here the case with `Object` is a different one

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key here is that Object is the super type of String[]

Java uses the most specific available method to resolve such cases. Null can be passed to both methods without compilation errors so Java has to find the most specific method here. The version with String[] is more specific - therefore it will be chosen for execution.

Answer (score 6):

[Someone else has had this question earlier, check this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/408091/java/java/null-type-data-type)

> If there are two cases to choose from, the compiler will first try to pick the more specific case. In this case, String will be picked over Object.

In the other question it was `String str` instead of `String[] s`

Thus, since `String[]` is a more specific datatype than its super type `Object`, it is picked.

Comment: the difference between here and there, is not String[] instead of String, but Object instead of AnObject

Comment: @guido This post and my comment to you talks about 2 different links. Please read the link in the first line of this post